Mount NFS doesnt work anymore after changing ip adres due VLAN
I have put my Synology NAS in a different VLAN then my computer. I changed the IP address in the etc/fstab file for the mounts. My Ubuntu pc is on 192.168.10.50 and my NAS is on 192.168.40.50. I can ping the NAS, so that is no problem. On my other windows computer it's working fine after I changed the IP address.
My last line of fstab gives analysis error:
# Mount NAS share Music Collection
192.168.40.50:volume1/"Music Collection" /home/John/nas/"Music Collection" nfs rw,user,intr 0 0

Besides that, I get an error:

access denied by server while mounting and:
created symlink /run/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.wants/rpc-statd.service -> /lib/systemd/system/rpsc.stadt.service

when I do
sudo mount -a

Anybody got a clue what I am doing wrong or things I can try to find a solution?

Today i first changed the ip address back to old one in the fstab file. Then i umount the nfs shares. I changed the fstab file with the new IP Address of the NAS. That still didnt work. Acces denied was in my Synolgy NAS with the shared folders:
NFS permissions
Go to Control Panel > Shared Folder.
Select the shared folder and click Edit > NFS Permissions.

I had only my old IP address in the NFS Permissions. After setting my new IP address it all worked fine.
